# Need help making Gallery slideshow with lightbox work correctly

Tags: gallery

I am adding pictures to a page, and would like them to be in a series of slideshows.

f'rinstance, I have 4 picture series that should be on the page and I would like the visitor to click on a thumbnail to open a lightbox. Each picture series would be represented by a single thumbnail, so there should be four thumbnails on the page only.

I installed Simbox2 plug-in it works and serves my needs nicely, but I have two problems:

1. all the pictures in the gallery show up on the page - thumbnail form - in a column. You can click on any one of them to open the lightbox, it shows that picture of the series, and then you can move forward or backward as well.
2. when I try to add another gallery to the page, all the pictures I upload end up being appended to the first gallery. And, they appear in the bottom of the column of thumbnails

Obvisously, I don't understand the gallery function and could use some enlightenment. I know it can be done, because I've seen it on some of the lightbox plug-in sites. I just can't figger it out.

Thanks!

- a -

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens because lightbox gets appended to every image . It would look like this in the source code

```
 <IMG src="your image" rel=lightbox">
```

You need to add a gallery name to the gallery so that it looks like this

```
 <IMG src="your image" rel="lightbox[gallery1]">
```